# Jinja2 Iterate over dictionary that contains list of dictionaries template error

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Python object that looks like this coming from flask:

```
data = {
  "sunday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "monday" : [{"key":"value"}], 
  "tuesday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "wednesday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "thursday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "friday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "saturday": [{"key":"value"}]
}
```

In my HTML file, I've tried the following:

```
// #1
{% for key, value in data.items %}
  {% for item in value %}
     <p>{{item.key}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

// #2
{% for key, value in data.items() %}
  {% for item in value %}
     <p>{{item.key}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

// #3
{% for key, value in data.items %}

{% endfor %}

// #4
{% for key, value in data.items() %}

{% endfor %}
```

All of these return the same error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.
```

The only thing that works is:

```
{% for key in data %}

{% endfor %}
```

But this returns nothing and I can't iterate further. How can I iterate over my dictionary that contains lists of dictionaries and print out values?

Comment: Attach your html code (all, not just a part). Error says that some block hasn't been closed

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a third loop:

```py
data = {
  "sunday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "monday" : [{"key":"value"}], 
  "tuesday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "wednesday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "thursday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "friday": [{"key":"value"}], 
  "saturday": [{"key":"value"}]
}
```

`data` is a dictionary, each of the values holds a list. Until here you're right. But in the list you have another dictionary, which you need to loop over as well:

```
{% for key, val in data.items() %}
    {% for entry in val %}
        {# You could also access item 0 if you know for a #}
        {# fact that the list always holds a single entry. #}
        {% for entry_key, entry_val in entry.items() %}
    <p>{{entry_key}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```